# How to iterate through a string in Lua and get individual pieces

Tags: string, lua, compare, iteration

I have a string:

```
line="123 123 test testing"
```

and I want to go through the pieces separated by space and check to see if each piece (123, 123, test, testing) matches a pre-determined sequence.

I know how to tokenize a string:

```
for token in string.gmatch(line,'%w+') do
    print (token)
end
```

I am not sure however how to iterate through each piece one by one and compare to my variable, `local var`.

Basically I want to be able to get each piece of the string, compare to variable `var`'s contents.

Here is a psudo-code:

```
Read file line by line { 
    Split every line by space (each line is in this format 123 456 string string) 
    Var1="123" 
    Var2="456" 
    If first token of the line= var1 then 
            If second token of the line=var2 then 
                    Print the line 
            End 
    End 
    }
```

Comment: So you know how to split a space-separated string and print each substring. So... what part are you missing here? Comparing a string to the contents of a variable? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the value of `var`? Provide a complete example and your expected result. And of course, your code.

Comment: You want to compare `token` in that loop against `var`?

Answer (score 1):

```
for v in str:gmatch('%s('..var..')%s') do
    print(v)
end
```

Without more information this is all I can think of.

Comment: Thank you all for your quick answers.
So here is a complete example/psudo code of what i want to do:

    Read file line by line {
       Split every line by space (each line is in this format 123 456 string string)
       Var1="123"
       Var2="456"

       If first token of the line= var1 then
             If second token of the line=var2 then
                   Print the line
             End
       End
    }
Hope this clears the problem I'm having.

Thank you all again

Comment: Sorry about my last ugly post, for some reason indentation on phone doesn't make the code, appear as code...

Comment: @Ali update your question itself with the pseudo code